# jQuery Mobile: How do you simulate the iOS slide-out navigation pattern on jQuery Mobile?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

**EDIT 2/13: The [Panels widget](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/panels/) in jQuery Mobile 1.3 now exists! Please use this instead.**

I'm trying to write a [custom CSS-based transition in jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html) to simulate the [slide-out navigation design pattern](http://kenyarmosh.com/blog/ios-pattern-slide-out-navigation/).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the navigation slide into view and take up 75% of the viewport space. The remaining 25% is filled with the remainder of the previous page.

Here's my CSS:

```
.slidenav.in { /*New page coming in*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-75%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slidenav-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidenav-in {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(-75%); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}

.slidenav.out { /*Old page going out*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slidenav-content-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidenav-content-out {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(75%); }
}

.slidenav.in.reverse { /*Old page coming in*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(75%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slidenav-content-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidenav-content-in {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(75%); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
}

.slidenav.out.reverse { /*New page going out*/
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slidenav-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidenav-out {
    from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-75%); }
}
```

I can't seem to get it to do what I want, though. It removes the old page entirely instead of leaving the remaining 25% of the page in view.

You can see what's happening here (Webkit browsers): http://jsbin.com/ukajeb/7

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2/13: The [Panels widget](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/panels/) in jQuery Mobile 1.3 now exists! Please use this instead.**

So I worked some more on this and, with the help of Firebug, discovered that after the keyframe animation was occurring, the original page was being reset to its original position and `display` set to `none`.

Knowing this, I started going through the jQuery Mobile docs a bit more thoroughly and found that there are [Page Transition Events](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/events.html) that you can bind to. More specifically, the `pageshow` and `pagehide` events.

Then I set the CSS of the original page manually:

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pagehide',function(event, ui){
    $(this).css({
        "display": "block",
        "-webkit-transform": "translateX(75%)"
    });
});
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
    $(this).css({
        "display": "",
        "-webkit-transform": ""
    });
});
```

Check it out here (Webkit browsers): http://jsbin.com/ukajeb/3

Hope someone else finds this useful as well!

**Note:** This demo uses jQuery Mobile 1.0.1, which only supports jQuery 1.6.4. This is why `.live()` was used rather than `.on()`. However, the upcoming [jQuery Mobile 1.1.0](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/) will support jQuery 1.7.1, so moving forward `.on()` should be used in place of the deprecated `.live()`.

Comment: Good work! - I know a few people might like that.  It's close to what facebook mobile is using for their menu structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fully help, but I took a look at this inside of firebug a bit. What I think is happening is when you complete the transition (even the partial one) the active page becomes the menu you are transitioning to. This means the last page is being hidden as it is no longer active. And in fact you can see when the transition completes the other page with "content" disappears.

You might try this on your link that invokes the menu - try using a dialog. You would still need to apply your custom transition there. I think what you are trying to accomplish you may also look into a plugin called "sub page" it may get you to the look you are trying to achieve. Also there is splitview (http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/) Alternately you could try messing around with the 1.2 branch of JQM and see if POPUP men may get you there as well. Essentially, it is a div that can sit on top of the existing active page.

```
<a href="foo.html" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

I originally was using a dialog with a slide up / down effect - but it became too troublesome in Android so we removed it.

I don't think JQM was really designed by default to keep two pages active and visible at once.

Comment: Good info, I'll check it out. Thanks.